# Straight line intersection for a general form

Tags: math, geometry, line

Although there are some posts regarding intersection of two straight lines in vector & standard forms, I am interested in computing the intersection for the general equations of two straight lines to avoid the problem of vertical line.

I have a total least square fitting straight line like the following form:

a(x - x_bar) + b(y - y_bar) = 0 (which goes through the mid point (x_bar,y_bar)).

This equation can be written in the general form like Ax+By+C = 0.

My question is that if I try to find the intersection of two of these lines (say, A1x+B1y+C1=0 & A2x+B2y+C2=0), should I simply solve these equations for x & y by substitution? Also, will that cover the problem of vertical line?

Comment: This is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should solve matrix equation (find inverse matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You might have done this at school under simultaneous equations. Take A2 time the first and A1 times the second giving A1 A2 x B1 A2 y + C1 A2 = 0 and A2 A1 x + B2 A1 y + C2 A1 = 0. Subtract these two gives (B1 A2 - B2 A1) y + (C1 - C2) =0 you can then solve for y, once you have found that x is easy to find.